# MySQL correct way to store BLOB (not saving it local disk)

Tags: php, mysql, curl, blob

In case i used **cURL** to download image and want to store image in **MySQL** field of type **BLOB** how can i go about it?
Normally i'd use **load_file()** mysql function for local file, however in this particular question i don't want to save file on disk on purpose.

raw image data from CURL is in variable **$image** i can display it like

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($image) . "' />";
```

Now when i add it to database however i getting error in queries using MySQL driver

```
$query = "INSERT into images ( image_blob ) VALUES ( '{$image}' )";
```

(note i am not using PDO or MySQLi driver for this example on purpose)

What should i do in this case, i could not find answer so i tried with one of following functions

```
addslashes($image) 
mysql_real_escape_string($image)
bin2hex($image)
base64_encode($image)
```

each one can solve the problem and store image, however which one is the right to use in this case?

P.S. Even though each function produces string of different length i noticed that file size reported in phpMyAdmin is same each time, why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (mysql) database queries use mysql_real_escape_string().

They are the same size because for blob data type MySQL stores the actual content of the blob externally, not in the table.

Comment: phpMyAdmin seem to show actual image file size e.g. [BLOB - 64.0KiB]
[BLOB - 20.7KiB]
[BLOB - 64.0KiB]
[BLOB - 9.4KiB]

Comment: In that case you may want to edit your question as it contradicts with this comment. I don't use phpMyAdmin so I was really just guessing.